# Find Out If Number Ranges Overlap in C

Tags: c, overlap

I have a very simple C program which when started, asks the user to input the 3 ranges themselves in the following format:

First Number Of First Range:

Second Number Of First Range:

First Number Of Second Range:

etc etc...
Up until

Second Number of Third Range:

I need to make sure that none of the ranges overlap with one another.

How would i go about this? (cant seem to find a decent relevant answer to this situation)

EDIT:

Im not just asked for someone to write the code as someone suggested very ignorantly below. I am only asking for a bit of help on how to logically go about this as i have been staring at the screen racking my brains for about 2 hours now trying to think of a way to do this without writing about 1000 lines of code.

I have also been doing C for approximately 13 days so obviously i dont know the ins and outs of its functions.

Comment: Im not asking for a program to copy. I asked "how would i go about this". IE, what is the logical way to do this.

If i could think of a way to do it, then i would of done it. I came here for help when i couldnt do it.......

Comment: If you downvote everyone who asks for a bit of a hint or help with getting their head around something which is new to them then there is no point in this site....

Comment: OP didn't ask for code. I don't know why there is a close vote and so many downvotes.

Comment: This is not about C, this is about logic.  Do yourself a favor and write out the criteria that must be met for each possible pair of ranges: one range can be inside the other, or overlap from the right or left side.  If none of the 3 conditions is met, they do not overlap.  Some tests can be omitted if ***but only if*** the ranges you get are guaranteed to be ordered.  Once you write out this logic it will be totally trivial to translate that to C - it's just a bunch of && and || 's :)

Comment: Being new to C, i was unsure if there was a function which could do this. I was hoping that by mentioning it was C, someone would pipe up and say use "x" function or something similar. Or do what Haccks did and just go straigt to the point :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Compare the upper limit of first range with lower limit of second range.

```
 if(uplfirst > lplsecond)
       printf("Overlap");
```

and same for others.

Comment: The easier way to think about it, as stated, is if you draw a number line and put your ranges on it, then you'll see clearly how each one overlaps each other and how this works

Comment: To be honest, i actually did that, and it still didnt click! - been a long day!

Comment: Haccks - thanks for getting me started on this. I have found a flaw in your suggestion however. If the two ranges were: (20-30) and (10-15) your code would return overlap. Obviously they dont. So i have extended the code to this: "if(uplfirst > lplsecond && uplsecond > lplfirst)" - Thankyou for providing a start for me though. I appreciate it :)

Comment: @Dr.Pepper; I did't provided complete solution. I just gave you a rough idea how to start with.